# What's the best way to link views and pass data between them?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a basic diary application that has two views: Add and Edit view. When user hits 'Add' button on Add view, the data is saved into database and simple message is shown. When user hits 'Update' button on Edit View, the data is updated and a last update stamp is added.

So far these views run independently. The Edit View by default loads the last saved entry and allows for that to be updated.

I want to update it so that upon successful addition of new diary entry on the Add View, it transitions to the Edit View to allow the user to Edit and Update if they want to. How do I link the views together and pass the relevant data to Edit View to know which Entry (database object) to fetch for edit? Also I would like to be able to use the Edit View independently to fetch a specified diary entry for example on a GET. So the Edit View is agnostic to whomever called it, it just knows which diary entry to load.

The code for Add and Edit View as they are now, are displayed below:

```
def addEntry(request):
   entryForm = None

   if request.method == "POST":
       entryForm = EntryForm(request.POST)

       if entryForm.is_valid():
           entryForm.save(commit = True)
           request.method = "GET"
           return entrySubmitted("Entry has been submitted")
       else:
           logger.info(entryForm.errors)
    else:    
        # Set up view with new entry form
        entryForm = EntryForm()

    template = getEntryViewTemplate(entryForm)

    return render(request, "DiaryEntry.html", template)



def editEntry(request):
   # Get the latest entry from the database
   entry = Entry.objects.last();

   if request.method == 'GET':
       entryForm = EntryForm(instance = entry)
   else:
       entryForm = EntryForm(request.POST, instance = entry)
       if entryForm.is_valid():
           entryForm.setLastUpdated(datetime.now())
           entryForm.save(commit = True)

   templateData = getEntryViewTemplate(entryForm)
   return render(request, "EditEntry.html", templateData)
```

Thanks in Advance,

Francis

Comment: Surely you just need to pass an ID parameter to the edit view and use that to determine which object to edit? The tutorial shows you exactly how to do that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman which tutorial are you referring to? Please excuse me I'm new to Django and Python. Thank you.

Comment: Most of the time when someone mentions linking views they completely overlook the fact that you are writing something designed for multiple users. Instead, you're redirecting to the *url* that corresponds with a particular view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look django documentation about Class Base View.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#

You can create a class, with different method.
Get, Post(create object), Put(Update object)

And you have a lot of methods and attributes usefull.
You can link your class view to a specific model (Entry) for example.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset

How do I link the views together and pass the relevant data to Edit View to know which Entry (database object) to fetch for edit? 
You need to pass ID Object to edit. Two solutions. In your Post data. Or by argument in your url.
http://your_web_site.com/entry/id_entry/
And you init your form with entry data

In your URL django you can link to url to your class base view.

```
    url(r'^entry/$', views.EntryView.as_view(), name='create_entry'),
    url(r'^entry/(?P<pk>[-\w/]+)$', views.EntryView.as_view(), name='update_entry'),
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks @Wilfried this answer helped me a great deal. I chose to pass id of the entry into my view

Comment: You are welcome. Do not hesitate to post your code edited and to accept the answer if this has solved your problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work